# Hashcode() and equals() implementation in View Class

Tags: android, view

Does `View` class overrides `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods? I want to create `HashMap` with `AdapterViews`

Comment: you do realize android is open source, right ? View code is here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to implement HashMaps and are wondering if `View` class or `AdapterViews` will take care of it?

Well, 
`View` **does not** implement `hashCode() and equals()` but they do **import MAPS**.

> For the solution;

**You will have to override the hashCode() and the equals()** function in your implementation.

See [implementing hash code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127155/gethashcode-for-similar-values/18127271#18127271) for further help. Another [Good source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That is great! I hoped they do not implement those methods.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter if `View` overrides those methods. Everything extends from `Object` so there will be an implementation for them. Whether or not the implementation is specific to `View` is (almost always) irrelevant. Therefore, you can use them as keys in a `Map`.

Edit: While I couldn't find anything about `View` and `hashcode()`, I did find this wonderful page in the Android documentation that explains the base Java class, [Object](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html). In this documentation, it explains how to implement a `hashcode()` method and what to do if an object doesn't support it (they recommend throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`). Therefore, I would have to assume that if a class in the Android library doesn't support `hashcode()`, Google would do the same thing.

Comment: I think the question is more : "is there a risk that 2 different views are considered equals and therefore unfit for hashmap key?"